# How to have different images change every second in a Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript that gets images in a folder called "pictures/" but i want this code writen so that i can have each Div different get different images from the folder i tell it to but i cant figure out how to set it up. im knew to this and i would appreciate the help:

```
 function displayImage(image) {
          document.getElementById("img").src = image;
           document.getElementById("img2").src = image;
            document.getElementById("img3").src = image;
      }

      function displayNextImage() {
          x = (x == images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function displayPreviousImage() {
          x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
          displayImage(images[x]);           
      }

      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 1000);
      }

      var images = [], x = -1;
      images[0] = "pictures/" + "1.jpg";
      images[1] = "pictures/" + "2.jpg";
      for(var y=2;y<4;y++){
      images[y]= "pictures/" + (y+1) + ".jpg";
      }
```

HTML:

```
    <div><img id="img" src="pictures/1.jpg">7</div>
<div><img id="img2" src="pictures/1.jpg">8</div>
<div><img id="img3" src="pictures/1.jpg">9</div>
```

Comment: Which images should be in each div?

Comment: different images from 3 different folders. i dont want them to preview the same images.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having the img as a class

HMTL

```
<div ><img class="imageNext" src="#">7</div>
<div ><img class="imageNext" src="#">8</div>
<div ><img class="imageNext" src="#">9</div>
```

Then use the .each() function of jQuery to change the image

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('div img.imageNext').each(function( i, e){
  //you would need to add your timer based code here
  $(e).attr('src','pictures/'+i+'.jpg')
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how will i be able to grave pictures from different folders? i only need each div to get the pictures from only the folder i assign each one to. each div will have its own folder to call

Comment: You'll need to define your divs a little more, are you just rotating through? like each div is the next folder? Then you could assign the divs a class, and use the each statement on the div and the attr would look like: $('img.imageNext',e).attr(...)

Answer (score 0):

### In your displayImage() method pass the index of image rather then image

and change the value of index such that it should not cause the ArrayOutOfBoundIndex error

then your displayImage() method would be like this

```
function displayImage(imageIndex) {
      document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
       document.getElementById("img2").src = images[x+1];
        document.getElementById("img3").src = images[x+2];
  }
```